# How do I remove both rows from a sample duplicate if one of them has an unwanted value?

Tags: r

I have a data frame that contains multiple observations of the same samples with six markers and that come from different data sources.

I want to consider two rows as "duplicates" if the following variables have the same values: data_source, sample_name and marker.
NOTE: When I say "duplicate" from now on, I do not mean rows that have identical values for ALL variables, just the ones I mentioned.

I want to filter the data into a new data frame that has removed the cases where one of the "duplicate" samples has an Undetermined intensity.

```r
df1 <- data.frame(data_source = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1","1", "1" , "1", "1", "1", "1","1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2"),
                 sample_name = c("x1", "x1", "x1","x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1","x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1"),
                 marker = c("A", "B", "C","D", "E", "F", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "A", "B", "C","D", "E", "F", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"),
                 intensity = c(9.74, 12.54, 15.32, 13.01, 15.83, 20.74, "Undetermined", 13.64, 15.13, 13.56, 15.72, 20.99, 13.63, 15.62, "Undetermined", 16.15, 20.15, 17.55, 13.14, 16.01, 10.52, 17.00, 19.89, 18.21),
                 end = c(9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 9, 8, 8, 7, 9, 8, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 9, 8, 8, 7, 9, 8),
                 status = c("good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good"))

print(df1)
   data_source sample_name marker    intensity end status
1            1          x1      A         9.74   9   good
2            1          x1      B        12.54   9   good
3            1          x1      C        15.32   9   good
4            1          x1      D        13.01   8   good
5            1          x1      E        15.83   8   good
6            1          x1      F        20.74   8   good
7            1          x1      A Undetermined   9   good
8            1          x1      B        13.64   8   good
9            1          x1      C        15.13   8   good
10           1          x1      D        13.56   7   good
11           1          x1      E        15.72   9   good
12           1          x1      F        20.99   8   good
13           2          x1      A        13.63   9   good
14           2          x1      B        15.62   9   good
15           2          x1      C Undetermined   9   good
16           2          x1      D        16.15   8   good
17           2          x1      E        20.15   8   good
18           2          x1      F        17.55   8   good
19           2          x1      A        13.14   9   good
20           2          x1      B        16.01   8   good
21           2          x1      C        10.52   8   good
22           2          x1      D           17   7   good
23           2          x1      E        19.89   9   good
24           2          x1      F        18.21   8   good
```

That is, I want to accomplish the above data frame but where rows 1+7 and 15+21 are removed since they are "duplicates" of which one of them has an intensity value as Undetermined (rows 7 and 15).

My original data frame contains >100000 observations with 38 variables but these are the ones that I want to filter with. I am interested in the rows that have an intensity value that is not Undetermined but I do not want to include them in the data frame if the duplicate row of the respective sample has an Undetermined intensity.
There are too many sample names to individually type them all so I can't have a filter with a specific value for that variable. The reason why I need to include data_source is to be able to separate the samples into duplicates (I do not want to compare the intensity of eg., rows 1, 7, 13 and 19 together but keep them separate like 1+7 and 13+19). Again, I cannot filter with a specific value for the data_source since the my original data frame is simply too huge.

Sorry to say that I don't really have any suggestions on how to solve this because I'm completely clueless. Here is the kind of solution I'm thinking about. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```r
df2 <- df1[df1$`end` <10 & `status`== "good" &`intensity`!="Undetermined" & **CODE TO CONDITIONALLY REMOVE THE SAMPLE DUPLICATES**,]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dplyr::group_by()` and `dplyr::filter()` for this. The `!any(...)` removes all rows with at least one row in the group having intensity as "Undetermined":

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  group_by(data_source, sample_name, marker) %>%
  filter(n() > 1 & !any(intensity == "Undetermined"))

## or more recent versions of dplyr using the .by command:

df1 %>%
  filter(n() > 1 & !any(intensity == "Undetermined"), 
         .by = c(data_source, sample_name, marker))
```

Output:

```
  data_source sample_name marker intensity   end status
   <chr>       <chr>       <chr>  <chr>     <dbl> <chr> 
 1 1           x1          B      12.54         9 good  
 2 1           x1          C      15.32         9 good  
 3 1           x1          D      13.01         8 good  
 4 1           x1          E      15.83         8 good  
 5 1           x1          F      20.74         8 good  
 6 1           x1          B      13.64         8 good  
 7 1           x1          C      15.13         8 good  
 8 1           x1          D      13.56         7 good  
 9 1           x1          E      15.72         9 good  
10 1           x1          F      20.99         8 good  
11 2           x1          A      13.63         9 good  
12 2           x1          B      15.62         9 good  
13 2           x1          D      16.15         8 good  
14 2           x1          E      20.15         8 good  
15 2           x1          F      17.55         8 good  
16 2           x1          A      13.14         9 good  
17 2           x1          B      16.01         8 good  
18 2           x1          D      17            7 good  
19 2           x1          E      19.89         9 good  
20 2           x1          F      18.21         8 good
```